# Android Imageview setOnTouchListener not working?

Tags: android, imageview, ontouchlistener

i'am using imageview on touch listener in this `motion event` not working  why this happen any one have idea regarding this help me.

here is my code

```
   img_View11.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {               
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {             
            Log.i("img_View11", "img_View11 _1");

            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Log.i("img_View11", "img_View11 _2");                                            
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                Log.i("img_View11", "img_View11 _3");    
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Log.i("img_View11", "img_View11 _4");
                break;               
            }               
            return false;
        }
    });
```

here my out put show like this `img_View11_1` and two `img_View11_2`

```
 Log.i("img_View11", "img_View11 _1");
 Log.i("img_View11", "img_View11 _2");
```

Question: Why MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE and MotionEvent.ACTION_UP not working ?

Comment: Return `true` from `onTouch()`.

Comment: @Luksprog true is working, is it possible to set only `ACTION_MOVE` of my imageview

Comment: I don't understand your comment(it's a question?). Even if you just care about `ACTION_MOVE` you still need to return `true` so the listener will keep getting the events.

Comment: present iam set 3 cases `ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_MOVE, ACTION_UP` in place of this set only `ACTION_MOVE` not working properly any other way solve this issue....

Comment: Also set the `ACTION_DOWN` to return true.

Answer (score 3):

Change "return false;" to  "return true;" so that it will continue to receive calls.